# jquery post request/response cross-domain

Tags: jquery, post, request, cross-domain, response

is it possible to make cross-domain jquery post request and get back a response. anyone know the format?

if not, does anyone know what else I can use on the client side in order make the request and get a response?

thanks.

Comment: You probably want to post up some code sample of what you're doing for your POST cross-domain request :)

Comment: @Alvin here's some code, hope it helps.        $(document).ready(function() {
 $.post('***THE URL***',
 function(xml) { //parse xml } });

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JSONP for a post.

There are other solutions, such as a local proxy (which obviates the need for JSONP at all, really).

---

Op has requested more info about a local proxy.  By local, I mean local to the server which is serving up the jQuery.  This is just a CURL post, which then echos out whatever is coming back in a object called data:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'a=hello&b=world'); // use your post data here.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$resp));
```

Comment: cant really find any tutorials on local proxy implementation. do you mind sharing one or any other simple methods that might work? thanks.

Comment: Added to my response for you.

Comment: I think by local proxy John means a local sever that makes server side request forward. Do you have a server-side scripting language you're using?

Comment: Yup.  I added a PHP variant above, since it is the easiest to show/follow.

Comment: Thanks @John Green - PageSpike ! I'll try this out.